# Prop value passed in template isn't rendering the actual value, but instead prints out the prop name

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm in the process of learning React and dabbling with `props`. I have a component where I've added these props and I'm then trying to give them values in another template.

The issue I'm having is that with my current setup (demoed below), it does't render the value I've passed in the prop, just says the prop code when inspecting.

For example, in `Homepage.js`, I have padded a value to the `id` prop (`id="screenOne"`). However, when inspecting the page, it prints out `id="{sectionID}"`.

I have followed several different guides ([example](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/beginners-guide-to-props-in-react/#:%7E:text=Props%20are%20used%20to%20store,learn%20about%20props%20in%20React.)) to see how to pass props, but none of them worked.

#### Screen.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

function Screen(props) {

  const sectionID = props.id;
  const tag = props.tag;
  const header = props.header;

  return(

    <div className="panel" id="{sectionID}">
      <Container>
        <Row className="justify-content-center align-items-center">

          <Col xs={12} md={6}>
            <div className="panel__left">
              <h1 className="panel__left-title">
                <span className="d-block">{tag}</span>
                <span className="d-block">{header}</span>
              </h1>
            </div>
          </Col>
          
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>

  )

}

export default Screen;
```

#### `Homepage.js`

```js
import React from "react";
import Screen from "../components/Screen/Screen";

class Homepage extends React.Component {
  render(){

    return (
      <section id="project">

        <Screen
          id="screenOne"
          tag="tag"
          header="header"
        />

      </section>
    );

  }
}

export default Homepage;
```

#### `App.js`

```js
import React from "react";
import Homepage from "./pages/Homepage";

function App() {
  return (
    <Homepage />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `id={sectionID}`. By including the quotes you're passing the literal string `"{sectionID}"`

Comment: @RobinZigmond -  that did the trick. Should I delete the question since it's considered a typo?

Comment: up to you. I voted to close as a typo but there is a fair argument that it's not strictly a typo and may help others. But feel free to delete it if you want to.

Comment: @RobinZigmond could you post an answer? I  believe many users will find this question useful

Comment: @Konrad OK, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the prop like this: `id={sectionID}`.

By including the quotes: `id="{sectionID}"` you're saying the prop value is the literal string `"{sectionID}"`, which is exactly the problem you've observed.